# How to initialize Value before submitting MVC form using j query?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC From :

```
@model CustomActivityViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CustomActivity", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @id = "customActivityForm", @class = "activityForm" }))
   {
     <div class="container" id="workordercategories">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorkOrderCategoriesName, new { @class = "" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkOrderCategoriesName, new { @class = "w100p mb0" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WorkOrderCategoriesName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>


                            <div class="container" id="activity">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Activity, new { @class = "" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Activity, new { @class = "w100p mb0" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Activity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary createActivity" id="createActivity">Create</button>
     </div>
   }
```

The View Model of the Form is:

```
 public class CustomActivityViewModel
    {
        [Required, Display(Name = "Work Category Name")]
        public string WorkOrderCategoriesName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
    }
```

The value of Activity and WorkOrderCateogry is initialized for the form now I need to initialize the valuof `WorkOrderID` before submitting the form. The value of workorder comes when we click button for the respective item to generate the form modal. Let's say `$(this).attr("data-id")`. Now I need to initialize the value of `workOrderID` to `$(this).attr("data-id")` before submitting.How can i do this?

My jquery Function is

```
 $(".createActivity").click(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));  // the value of work order ID to be assigned
            });
```

it dosent works. How can i fix this?

Comment: have tryied  onmousedown

Comment: if you are able to put it in a data attribute, why not just use a `@Html.HiddenFor` and pre-populate it in your model server side

Comment: @Pete I an mew to this, How can that be done? I researched about html.hiddenfor but that didn't go well

Comment: How did you add the data attribute to the html? Also what didn't work with the hidden input?

Comment: @Pete here by this was ``` <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm addCustomActivity" data-id=@item.OrderId>Add Custom Activity</a> ```

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.WorkOrderID, new { Value = item.OrderId }}`